# Crystal Reports data fields positioning

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I need the data that is retrieved from the data base (2 columns: **ID** and **Value**) to be placed in report in specific way, i.e not Vertically as always but horizontally. The final view must be something like this:

> **ID**   **Value**            **ID**   **Value**            **ID**   **Value**
>
> ---
>
> 1    'First'              2    'Second'         3    'Third'
>   
>   4    'Fourth'           5    'Fifth'              6    'Sixth'
>   
>   and so on...

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section Expert - Details - Format with Multiple Columns - Layout - Across then Down